# Making view only available to registered users with registration redux?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I'm making a simple Django application, I've implemented django registration redux with two step email verification, using the standard default templates.

I know want to add a simple HTML page that is only accessible to registered users:

```
 my_project
    /settings.py
    /urls.py
templates
   /only_accessible_to_users.html
   /registration
manage.py
my_application
   /models.py
   /admin.py
   /views.py
   /urls.py
```

In `/my_project/urls.py` I have the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
  url(r'^finance/', include('my_application.urls'))
]
```

In `my_application/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.testing, name='testing')]
```

Finally in `my_application/view.py`:

```
def testing(request):
   return HttpResponse("<h2>Hey!</h2>")
```

How can I render a HTML page here after validating that it's being requested by a registered user?

Comment: Have you read the comprehensive docs on authentication, where this is fully described?

Answer (score 0):

You can use render function and pass the html template

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def testing(request):
    return render(request, template_name="test_template.html")
```

Comment: Yes but how I restrict the path "103.44.33.XX:8000/finance" to just registered users? Otherwise anyone can access this page

Comment: you can add login_required decorator